# Magento price format showing wrong after changing language

Tags: magento, format, locale, currency

Price formatting shows wrong after changing the default language English to another language.

In my main website it outputs like `Rs.1,200,000.00` but after changing the language from English to another language its outputs like `Rs.1.200.000,00`.

How can I fix that issue?

Comment: To which language you shifted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the priceformat in this file:

> lib/Zend/Locale/Data/[lang].xml

You can search for:

```
<numbers>
    <symbols>
        <decimal>.</decimal>
        <group>,</group>
    </symbols>
</numbers>
```

Edit
changed folder name local to locale